# Greater than in command line

Tags: command-line, command, scons

I'm trying to understand this Scons command:

```
env.Command('foo.out', 'foo.in', "sed 's/x/y/' < $SOURCE > $TARGET")
```

What do the `<` and `>` mean in `sed 's/x/y/' < $SOURCE > $TARGET`?

Comment: [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that input to sed will be coming from file $SOURCE and output will be saved to $TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's `scons`, but `<` redirects the given file to the input stream of the given command (in your case, writes file to the input of `sed`); and `>` redirects the output stream of the command to some other file.

So, basically, you run `sed` on `$SOURCE` file and redirect the results to `$TARGET` file.